# Why is sbt missing dependency on Vaadin project

Tags: maven, sbt, vaadin

I've created a Vaadin project using maven, and installed the war in my local maven repository.
This project defines a public class, `com.whatever.User`.

Then, I created an sbt project wherein I'd like to add a depenecy on the Vaadin project - in order to test it's logic. In the build.sbt file of my sbt project I've added:

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome+"/.m2/repository"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.whatever" % "something" % "1.0"
)
```

After reloading the sbt project I tried using the User object from inside the sbt project. But I'm getting this error:

```
> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/me/projects/something-test/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[error] /Users/me/projects/something-test/src/main/scala/TryingUser.scala:1: object whatever is not a member of package com
[error] import com.whatever.User
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] {file:/Users/me/projects/something-test/}default-1bc94a/compile:compile: Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 2012-apr-25 13:44:56
```

what am I missing? Why isn't sbt adding this dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see sbt, or indeed any other build tool, being able to use war files as dependencies. Think about what the classpath passed to `javac` or `java` would look like. The compiler will presumably just see it as a standard zip file and won't be aware that the actual classes are in `WEB-INF/classes`.

I think you'd need to package the classes as a jar file and use that as a dependency.